# How to send extjs data via json

Tags: json, extjs

i am working extjs. i want to send textfields data via json. So i have written code as-

```
Ext.define('Balaee.controller.kp.WordController',{
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores: ['kp.WordStore'],
    models: ['kp.WordModel'],
    views: ['kp.Word.Word'],
    refs:[
       {
            ref:'wordtext',
            selector:'textfield[name=wordtext]'
       },
       ],
    init: function() {
        console.log('Inside word controller');
        this.control(
                {
            'Word button[action=SearchAction]':
            {
                click:this.SearchWord
            },

        });//End of control
    },//End of init() function

    SearchWord:function(button)
    {
        var j = Ext.getCmp('wordtext').getValue();
        console.log("word is:"+j);


                            var wordObject = Ext.ModelManager.create(
                {

                    word:Ext.getCmp('wordtext').getValue(),
                },'Balaee.model.kp.WordModel');


        wordObject.save({    
            success: function(record, operation) 
            {
                console.log("registration successssssssssss  "+record);
            },//End of success function
            failure: function(record, operation) 
            {
                console.log("Inside failure functionnnnn");
            },//End of failure function
            callback: function(record, operation)
            {
                console.log("Inside callback functionnnnnn");   
                console.log(record);
            }//End of callback function
        });// End of
    },


});//End of Controller
```

But its always going in failure function. So what additional changes i need to do. please can someone please help me...

Comment: From the docs re: failure - "The function to be called upon unsuccessful completion of the sync. The failure function is called when one or more operations returns an exception during processing (even if some operations were also successful). In this case you can check the batch's exceptions array to see exactly which operations had exceptions."  Look at the exceptions array, see what the issue is, and then post back here if you have questions about how to resolve the exceptions you've received.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to create your instance of WordModel :

```
    var wordObject = Ext.create(
      'Balaee.model.kp.WordModel',
      { word : j }
    );
```

Or maybe you need to configure the proxy in the model